# How to create table with a column computed by another table in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql

How to create table with a column computed by another table in SQL Server?

For example:

**TableA**:

```
    Name   SerialNoStart  SerialNoEnd
    A        1              3
    B        2              4
    C        1              1
```

I want create a new table with serial number between `SerialNoEnd` and `SerialNoStart`

The new table as following:

`TableB`:

```
   Name    SerialNo
   A          1
   A          2
   A          3
   B          2
   B          3
   B          4
   C          1
```

How to make it? Thanks!

Comment: The thing you want is probably View.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can split the data out using a recursive CTE, similar to this:

```
;with data(name, SerialNoStart, SerialNoEnd) as
(
    select name, SerialNoStart, SerialNoEnd
    from TableA
    union all
    select name, SerialNoStart +1, SerialNoEnd
    from data
    where SerialNoStart +1 <= SerialNoEnd
)
select name, SerialNoStart as SerialNo
from data
order by name
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/3fd18/1)